# How to check if two Tensor shapes are the same including None?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I'd like to check if two tensors have the same shape.

Suppose I have some tensors like this:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])
```

I added `assert a.shape == b.shape`. However, this fails, perhaps due to the None. Indeed `a.shape` = `(?, 1)`, and also `b.shape` is `(?, 1)`. They look same to me.

If there is no None, it works OK.

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 3])
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 3])
assert a.shape == b.shape  # True
```

How can I ignore None in the shape checking?

In summary:

```
1: a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 3])
2: b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 3])
3: assert a.shape == b.shape  # True
4: 
5: a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])
6: b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])
7: assert a.shape == b.shape  # False
```

I want to get the assertion in line 7 to be True.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `a.shape.as_list() == b.shape.as_list()` to compare two [`tf.TensorShape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape) objects for "equality". However, you should be careful when doing this, because if the two shapes contain `None` in the same location then the tensors with those shapes are not guaranteed to have the same size in that dimension.

(It would be useful to be able to represent "symbolic" dimensions like `batch_size` in a `tf.TensorShape`, which would make equality testing more useful. We're looking at extensions to the API to allow this in future versions of TensorFlow.)

Comment: Thanks! If we have something like tf.TensorShape.assert_same(), it would be wonderful.

Comment: Another option is to use `tf.assert_equal(a.shape, b.shape)` although it does not work with partially known shapes.

Comment: You can also use `a.shape.is_compatible_with(b.shape)`, cf [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape#is_compatible_with)